# Different from assembly for pass by value and pass by const ref

Tags: c++, gcc, clang

Suppose we have code like this:

```
template<typename T>
struct StrongValue{
    constexpr const T &operator()() const {
        return value;
    }

    T &operator()(){
        return value;
    }

    constexpr const T &get() const {
        return value;
    }

    T &get(){
        return value;
    }

    T value;
};

using myint = int; // try double too

using m = StrongValue<myint>;

myint sum2(const m &a, const m &b){
    return a() + b();
}

myint sum2a(const m a, const m b){
    return a() + b();
}

myint sum1(myint a, myint b){
    return a + b;
}

int main(){
    constexpr m a{5};
    constexpr m b{5};

    return sum2a(a, b);
}
```

in both clang and gcc, -O3 assembly looks like this:

```
sum2(StrongValue<int> const&, StrongValue<int> const&):
  mov eax, DWORD PTR [rsi]
  add eax, DWORD PTR [rdi]
  ret
sum2a(StrongValue<int>, StrongValue<int>):
  lea eax, [rdi+rsi]
  ret
sum1(int, int):
  lea eax, [rdi+rsi]
  ret
main:
  mov eax, 10
  ret
```

Why `sum2` is compiled like this?

Is this because the compiler will change the function signature, if it omit the reference, so it is not allowed to do so.

Is this means, if is not inlined, `sum2` is more expensive than `sum2a` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why sum2 is compiled like this?

That’s expected. For sum2 you’re passing two references. Reference and `const` are C++ things, CPUs don’t have them, for CPUs they’re just pointers. Therefore, in the function, the code has to fetch two values from memory and sum them.

Two other versions receive arguments by value.

For all 3 versions, the compiler choose to use `__regcall` calling convention that’s why the two arguments are passed in `RSI` and `RDI` registers. That’s how the two other versions were able to compute the result in just a single instruction.

> Is this means, if is not inlined, sum2 is more expensive than sum2a?

Generally, yes. You should not pass integers by const reference, pass them by values instead. However, the exact performance impact can be negligible, the only way to find out is profiling.

Comment: but without inline / static / anonymous namespace, the compiler is not allowed to rewrite `sum2` and must use pointers?

Comment: also if this was in external file, function will be never inlined?

Comment: Compilers usually respects function prototypes.
Modern compilers have various features that help in such cases, VC++ has global optimization a.k.a. link-time code generation, LLVM has link time optimization. They will probably inline such simple functions even across files, getting rid of RAM references. But for best performance, it’s IMO more reliable to write code in a way that helps the compiler to make efficient code with less trickery.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that the parameters to `sum2` are essentially pointers while the parameters to `sum2a` are values. This implies that in `sum2` the pointers must be dereferenced to get to the actual values that can then be added while in `sum2a` you can add the values right away.

It is a common mistake to overuse constant references. For objects with cheap copying it is often better to pass parameters by value.